# Does Twilio allow for Zoom Phone connections?

Tags: twilio

Marketing text broadcasts are sent out from a phone number generated by Twilio that was once connected to Weave. As a firm, we switched to Zoom Phone and all of the text replies to our broadcasts are seemingly lost since it was tied to our old Weave account that we no longer have access to; can/how do I reassign the Twilio number to Zoom Phone if possible?

Apart from creating a ticket with Twilio Support, I have not tried anything to resolve this issue from Zoom's end.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly elaborate on your issue a bit more for clarification if possible.

I hope the following articles will help you to solve your issue:

[How to connect Twilio with Zoom](https://zapier.com/apps/twilio/integrations/zoom)
And [integrate Twilio and Zoom](https://integrately.com/integrations/twilio/zoom)

And If you want to configure your Twilio number from the Twilio console, kindly look into this article, it provides the configuration guidelines.

[Configure a Twilio Phone Number to Receive and Respond to Messages](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136047-Configure-a-Twilio-Phone-Number-to-Receive-and-Respond-to-Messages#h_5fd3801f-8241-421f-ad0f-8fb6c25ba68c)